# Using URW Grotesk in headers for page numbers

Tags: fonts, header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to use URW Grotesk in the header. The format I want is:
RE chapter name LE page number, LO section name, RO page number.

I have modified the example given in `fancyhdr` documentation to change the font to required one. I have managed to get the section and chapter name in the required font, but am unable to change the font for `\thepage` and it defaults to main font of the document. How can one change the page number font as well?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{{\fontfamily{ugq}\selectfont #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{{\fontfamily{ugq}\selectfont #1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand{\grotsq}{%
\fontfamily{ugq}\footnotesize\selectfont}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\grotsq \thepage} % this seems to have no effect
\fancyhead[LO]{\grotsq \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\grotsq \leftmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\chapter{The Start}
\section{alpha}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\section{beta}
\lipsum
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `\pagestyle{fancy}`. Without that, you get the page style `headings` which ignores the definitions from the `fancyhdr` package.

(You're getting the URW Grotesk for the chapter title because you added the `\fontfamily...\selectfont` command to the `\markboth` command which you probably don't want to do).

Comment: thanks, it worked. but for the first page of the chapter it is still reverting to the main font in the footer.

Comment: You can get the documentation for fancyhdr by doing `texdoc fancyhdr`. There's a section in the documentation about redefining `\pagestyle{plain}` that will address how to get that part working.